# What is the Android Geocoder response structure?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I'm using Geocoder to fetch addresses for some coordinates. It gives the result addresses in Address object, I'm trying to study the Address object so that I can rearrange the various attributes for user display (for example Premises, area, landmark, locality, sublocality, city, state).

I assume the Geocoder object used to be a bit different previously and had a lot many address lines, but currently it has only one and all comma separated phrases are not matchiing with the rest of the body which it provides below.

The below JSON structure for reference:

```
1> Delhi Address: [
{
"mAddressLines": {
  "0": "E46, Lodhi Colony, Sector 3G, Rohini, Delhi, 110085, India"
},
"mAdminArea": "Delhi",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "E46",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 28.703985300000003,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Delhi",
"mLongitude": 77.1024425,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "110085",
"mPremises": "E46",
"mSubAdminArea": "North West Delhi",
"mSubLocality": "Rohini"
}
]

2> Delhi Address: [
{
"mAddressLines": {
  "0": "684, Pocket 7, Sector 2, Rohini, Delhi, 110085, India"
},
"mAdminArea": "Delhi",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "684",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 28.700565400000002,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Delhi",
"mLongitude": 77.0993105,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "110085",
"mPremises": "684",
"mSubAdminArea": "North West Delhi",
"mSubLocality": "Rohini"
},
{
"mAddressLines": {
  "0": "Himalaya Apartment, Guru Gowalkar Marg, Pocket 00, Sector 2, Rohini, Delhi, 110085, India"
},
"mAdminArea": "Delhi",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "Himalaya Apartment",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 28.7004086,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Delhi",
"mLongitude": 77.09895829999999,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "110085",
"mPremises": "Himalaya Apartment",
"mSubAdminArea": "New Delhi",
"mSubLocality": "Rohini",
"mThoroughfare": "Guru Gowalkar Marg"
}
]

3> Hyderabad Address: [
{
"mAddressLines": {
  "0": "Rinda Legend Capital Mall, Main Rd, Subhash Nagar, Badi Chowdi, Koti, Hyderabad, Telangana 500095, India"
},
"mAdminArea": "Telangana",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "Rinda Legend Capital Mall",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 17.3852123,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Hyderabad",
"mLongitude": 78.48660459999999,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "500095",
"mPremises": "Rinda Legend Capital Mall",
"mSubAdminArea": "Ranga Reddy",
"mSubLocality": "Koti",
"mThoroughfare": "Main Road"
},
{
"mAddressLines": {
  "0": "5-1-314, Main Rd, Subhash Nagar, Badi Chowdi, Koti, Hyderabad, Telangana 500095, India"
},
"mAdminArea": "Telangana",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "5-1-314",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 17.3852895,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Hyderabad",
"mLongitude": 78.4865963,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "500095",
"mSubAdminArea": "Hyderabad",
"mSubLocality": "Koti",
"mSubThoroughfare": "5-1-314",
"mThoroughfare": "Main Road"
},
{
"mAddressLines": {
  "0": "Omnitech InfoSolutions, 1st Floor, Bulding No 17, Main Rd, Goutam Nagar, Badi Chowdi, Kachiguda, Hyderabad, Telangana 501301, India"
},
"mAdminArea": "Telangana",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "Omnitech InfoSolutions",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 17.385044,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Hyderabad",
"mLongitude": 78.486671,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "501301",
"mPremises": "Omnitech InfoSolutions",
"mSubAdminArea": "Ranga Reddy",
"mSubLocality": "Kachiguda",
"mSubThoroughfare": "1st Floor, Bulding No 17",
"mThoroughfare": "Main Road"
},
{
"mAddressLines": {
  "0": "Mobile Tower, Main Rd, Goutam Nagar, Badi Chowdi, Kachiguda, Hyderabad, Telangana 500095, India"
},
"mAdminArea": "Telangana",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "Mobile Tower",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 17.385044,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Hyderabad",
"mLongitude": 78.486671,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "500095",
"mPremises": "Mobile Tower",
"mSubAdminArea": "Ranga Reddy",
"mSubLocality": "Kachiguda",
"mThoroughfare": "Main Road"
},
{
"mAddressLines": {
  "0": "Saini Industries, 1-47/2, Fateh Nagar, Fateh Nagar, Gandhi Nagar, Badi Chowdi, Kachiguda, Hyderabad, Telangana 500018, India"
},
"mAdminArea": "Telangana",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "Saini Industries",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 17.385047399999998,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Hyderabad",
"mLongitude": 78.4866596,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "500018",
"mPremises": "Saini Industries",
"mSubAdminArea": "Hyderabad",
"mSubLocality": "Kachiguda"
}
]
```

Can any one provide some insight as to why the mAddressLine doesn't match with the rest of the body?

**EDIT:**
My doubt is for example the 1st one AddressLine is:

```
"E46, Lodhi Colony, Sector 3G, Rohini, Delhi, 110085, India"
```

But rest of the body:

```
"mAdminArea": "Delhi",
"mCountryCode": "IN",
"mCountryName": "India",
"mFeatureName": "E46",
"mHasLatitude": true,
"mHasLongitude": true,
"mLatitude": 28.703985300000003,
"mLocale": "en_US",
"mLocality": "Delhi",
"mLongitude": 77.1024425,
"mMaxAddressLineIndex": 0,
"mPostalCode": "110085",
"mPremises": "E46",
"mSubAdminArea": "North West Delhi",
"mSubLocality": "Rohini"
```

doesn't have 'Lodhi Colony' or 'Sector 3G', what are those? Instead Locality is showing as 'Delhi', it's not a locality, it's the whole city.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, there is a built-in structure to deserialize the Geocoder response

```
List<android.location.Address> addresses =
 geocoder.getFromLocationName("your-address",1);
```

Comment: I'm using 

     addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 5);

But, the Address when converted as a json creates the above structure, I don't have a problem with the structure, but there are discrepancies between the address line and the lower part of the body.